# How to display featured products in cms homepage...?

Tags: magento-1.9, featured-product

I installed this module(https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/featured-products-10.html) but i don't know.

How to display this in my cms homepage?

Answer (score 3):

you can create attribute for product `is_featured` value `yes or no` and create collection of filter product.

here is the link would help u.

[Featured products on Magento frontpage](http://inchoo.net/magento/featured-products-on-magento-frontpage-tutorial/)

Comment: Yes, if you haven't this attribute you can create it

Answer (score 1):

I've just copied the `How It Works` from the extension page in Magento Connect.

```
How it works

Set Featured Products: Go to the report "Catalog > Manage Featured Products" and set some products as featured.
Configuration Settings: Go to the report “System > Configuration > Catalog > Featured Product” and configure Show Featured Product On, Block Title and Number of Products.
Check Front end: Check Featured Products block displayed on home page , category page and sidebar.
```

In the `Configuration Settings` for the Featured Products, you will need to select just the `Home Page`, if you want the featured products to appear just in the home page.

You can comment if you need help after doing the above steps.